# Limit of the sequence $z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Hello I am working on the following question:

For $c = \frac{2-i}{8}\in\mathbb{C}$, define $z_0 = 0$ and $z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c$. We want to determine if this converges. I am trying to do it this way:

Suppose the limit exists, call it $L$, then $L = L^2 + c$, solving it there are two possible roots $w_1 = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}i$ and $w_2 = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}i$.
Now we wanted to try to prove the limit is $w_1$ or $w_2$, after some factoring I got:

$$|z_{n+1} - w_1| = |z_n^2 + c - w_1| = |z_n-w_1||z_n+w_1|  $$

Now I wanted to show somehow $|z_n+w_1|$ is always bounded by some constant $0 < \alpha < 1$, so we would have:

$$ |z_{n+1} - w_1| \le \alpha|z_n-w_1| $$

and this would means the $(z_n)$ converges to $w_1$ (Or we can do the same thing for $w_2$, I am not sure which one is the limit yet). Could someone help me to find this bound $\alpha$? Or if this approach is not very doable, could someone give me some hint? I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: In the closed disc $|z - w_j|  \leq \rho $  for real $\rho > 0$  we know $|z+w_j| \leq \rho + |w_j|$  by the triangle inequality.  In particular, what if $\rho = |w_j| \;  \; ? \;  \hspace{15mm}$

Comment: @WillJagy, that should be $|z+w_j| \leq \rho + 2|w_j|$, no? Since $z+w_j = (z-w_j)+2w_j$.

Comment: Am I the first one to bring up the name of Mandelbrot here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us show the limit is $L=\frac 14(1-i)$. We have first of all
$$
|z_1-L| =\left|c-L\right|=\frac 18\ .
$$
Assume inductively $|z_n-L|\le \frac 18$. Then we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
|z_{n+1}-L|
&=|z_n^2+c-L|
\\
&=|z_n^2-L^2|
\\
&=|z_n + L|\cdot |z_n-L|
\\
&=|(z_n-L) + 2L|\cdot |z_n-L|
\\
&\le\Big(|z_n-L| + 2|L|\Big)\cdot |z_n-L|
\\
&\le\underbrace{\left(\frac 18 + \frac{4\sqrt 2}8\right)}_{:=\alpha}\cdot |z_n-L|
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $\alpha<1$ we obtain inductively first $|z_{n+1}-L|$.

Then rewriting the same chain we obtain a wanted inequality of the shape $|z_{n+1}-L|\le\alpha|z_n-L|$.

$\square$

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is very helpful!